# Why does my button make my function open in a different window?

Tags: javascript, function, button

I'm trying to make my code execute my function in the same window but it always overwrites the current window with a new one that runs just the function, of course this brings my program to a full stop. How can I change my code so that it opens in the same window? (New to Java)

```
<button onclick="blackFemale()">Black Female</button>


<script>
document.write("Click the button of the character you would like to be, then click play.");

function blackFemale() {
character = "black female";
document.write("You are a ", character, ".");
var x = document.createElement("IMG");
x.setAttribute("src", "IntroImages/FemaleBlack.jpg");
x.setAttribute("width", "304");
x.setAttribute("width", "228");
x.setAttribute("alt", "black female");
document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```

Help would be appreciated, I was very nervous when asking this question due to the newbieness of it, hah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.write` overwrites the whole page.you can append it to body.

```
<button onclick="blackFemale()">Black Female</button>
```

js:

```
function blackFemale() {
    character = "black female";
    var text =document.createTextNode("You are a " + character + ".");
    document.body.appendChild(text);
    var x = document.createElement("IMG");
    x.setAttribute("src", "IntroImages/FemaleBlack.jpg");
    x.setAttribute("width", "304");
    x.setAttribute("width", "228");
    x.setAttribute("alt", "black female");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```